# Energy Interpretation of Quantum Effective Action From Weinberg's "The Quantum Theory of Fields"

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conventions, vacuum, time-evolution, s-matrix-theory

In section 16.3 of Weinberg, he attempts to prove that the effective potential energy $V(\phi)$ is equal to the minimum energy density of a state with field expectation value $\phi$. I am confused about the very beginning of the argument, which is screen-shotted below:

[image: Screenshot from the relevant portion of Weinberg]

The argument appears to be using an adiabatic approximation to show that the past and future vacuum states only differ by a phase. From the adiabatic approximation, we would more specifically say that $$|VAC,out\rangle=\exp({\color{red}{-}iE[\mathcal{J}]T})|VAC,in\rangle\tag{A}$$

Wouldn't this then imply that 
$$\langle VAC,out|VAC,in\rangle_J=\exp(\color{red}{+}iE[\mathcal{J}]T)~?\tag{B}$$

And so $$W[J]=\color{red}{+}E[\mathcal{J}]T~?\tag{C}$$ If this is correct, it appears to screw up the following argument in the section.

Comment: Please do not post images of texts you want to quote, but *type it out instead* so it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143136) instead.

Comment: My apologies, I got the idea to do this from a related post: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89091/  Would you like me to edit my post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[S-matrix theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-matrix_theory) (e.g. Weinberg's correct formulas) typically refers to the [Heisenberg picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture). OP is presumably thinking of the [Schroedinger picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_picture), and thereby obtaining opposite time evolution.

References:

1. S. Weinberg, *Quantum Theory of Fields,* Vol. 2, 1995; Section 16.3.
2. J.J. Sakurai, *Modern Quantum Mechanics,* 1994; Chapter 2.

Comment: Is there a good explanation for the difference in sign? Do you have a reference which describe the adiabatic approximation in the Heisenberg picture?

Comment: I updated the answer.